# Auditing with spring data jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a spring web application  with Spring Boot(v2.3.3)  and Spring Data. I have a table assessment that contains the following columns:

1. Id
2. Name
3. Address
4. Version

My use case is any changes of name and address in the table assessment a new row should be created and the version incremented with the same id.

So basically only when either the address or name are updated a new record should be inserted in the assessment table an example is shown below:

Existing record:

```
 Id       - 23
 Name     - John
 Address  - Southend
 Version  - 1
```

For example, the name has been updated to Ryan and there should be two rows as follows:

```
 Id       - 23
 Name     - John
 Address  - Southend
 Version  - 1

 Id       - 23
 Name     - Ryan
 Address  - Southend
 Version  - 2
```

So basically any changes in the name and address should be audited in assessment table and the version should be incremented.

I have seen hibernate envers for auditing but a new audit table needs to be created and therefore I cannot insert it in the assessment table and also I don't know how to generate the version number.

I can write the code programmatically to achieve this but is there any other available auditing tool that I can achieve it please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your main entity should have columns Id, Name, Address (not version). And you should put @Audit over entity. After that, you should generate database table scripts (see, for example, method main in the org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport).
You will see in script the main and archive table (with the _aud suffix). It will contain the Id,Name, Address, rev. the rev field is your version. When you change the name to Ryan in the main entity and commit, envers automatically adds a new entry to the archive table.

Answer (score 0):

If trigger is supported, try trigger, as it will cover cases updated directly from DB.